# Can anyone find the source code for the chatbot Luna?

Tags: chat-bots

[This AI](http://bigthink.com/elise-bohan/the-most-human-ai-youve-never-heard-of-meet-luna) is really human-like and allegedly doesn't give pre-programmed responses. It's makers Robots without Borders say the project is open source but I couldn't find the code anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can't find the source code because it doesn't exist. The whole thing was a 2015 kickstarter scam, and now it's a patreon scam. All the tech "demos" are obviously pre-scripted videos.

There was [actually a question on Quora about it](https://www.quora.com/Is-Luis-Aranas-AI-Luna-robot-for-real-or-is-it-a-scam-to-raise-funds), in which one of the answerers managed to find, among other things, the question and answer that his fake AI gave in one of the videos.

Comment: After reading the Quora post I do not feel that it is a scam.

Comment: @sage yeah. It's not a sure thing. The review could have been posted by anyone. There's nothing to show it's legit, but I don't think there's strong proof for it being a scam either. The QA thing isn't sure proof either.

Comment: @harsh99 The fact that his (solo developed) super-AI, that is "completely unscripted," answered 2 complicated social questions with answers that were both found on Quora is pretty damning evidence. Add the "open source" (but not anywhere) aspect of the project, the failed kickstarter, the patreon, the only tech demos being youtube videos, and you have what should be an obvious scam. It's sad that anyone would fall for it and donate money to that scam artist. He claims to have an AI more advanced than anything at Google/Facebook/Microsoft and can't prove it with a simple web demo.

Comment: @sage The fact that the open source code isn't available anywhere troubled me too. And yes, I also noticed the Kickstarter didn't even get $150. So yeah, I guess it's a scam. Thanks!

Comment: However, I'm tempted to add it might be programmed to fetch answers from the web.

Comment: While I also believe it's a scam, there is no evidence to back up the claims you make in your answer, either. Do I believe the youtube videos are scripted/pre-programmed responses? Yep. Has anyone, such as yourself, proved it? Nope. Has the author admitted they're fake? Again, nope. So, ironically, the information contained in your answer is no more reliable than the information you're criticizing.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy let me know if you have thoughts on how we might edit this answer to be less inflammatory, and more objective about not being able to have absolute certainty.  (Also, your thoughts on [this response](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/6008/1671) by Luna's creator, and how we might balance the two perspectives. My feeling is, in regards to claims, we have to be wary if it's not a research paper or a live product.  The response didn't incline me to close this answer, but your comments that this answer should be modified are salient.)